# Pull members up one time intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, abstract-class, member, intellij-14

Suppose I have an abstract class called Data:

```
public abstract class Data{

}
```

And 2 derived classes Data1 and Data2.

```
public Data1 extends Data{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int value;
}
```

And

```
public Data2 extends Data{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String category;
}
```

Is there  a way in intellij to pull **id, name** members up from both Data1, Data2 classes into Data class in one time operation without going into each class?

Answer (score 0):

Pull members up in  intellij with

**1.Click Refactor**

**2.Click pull members up**

[image]

Comment: I guess this needs 2 times, one for each child class.